# leafletjs - Polyline array push error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined "

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet

I am fairly new to leaflet js (picked it up about 5 hours ago), great little tool. I've run into an issue and after scouring the net, figured I'd ask.

I have the following code:

```
$.getJSON('json/data/url', function(data) {
        var latlngs = [];
        $.each(data,function(key,value){
            latlngs.push([value.lat, value.lon]);
        });
        var polyline = L.polyline(latlngs, polyline_options).addTo(map);
});
```

> Sample JSON: [{"lat":"52.168333333333","lon":"20.967833333333"},{"lat":"52.164","lon":"20.969333333333"}]

However I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

I have done some basic debugging like console logging the var latlngs and it appears to be a properly formatted array.

I'm at a loss as to what I am doing wrong.

Comment: what is 'polyline_options' ?

Comment: var polyline_options = {
    color: '#00A1DE',
    weight: '3',
   };

Comment: try removing the 'var' from that line, check what its value is using e.g. Chrome dev. console

Comment: No joy, I get the same error

Answer (score 5):

Your data has latitude & longitude values as strings. They need to be numbers. Either make them numbers in the data or use `parseFloat()` to convert them to numbers in Javascript.